Kafka "No subject alternative DNS name matching localhost found" error
I'm trying to setup kafka with SASL SSL and ACL but stuck with a problem with administration of broker.
There is my docker compose:
`version: "2"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.6
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: zookeeper
    user: root
    ports:
        - "2181:2181"
    environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/zookeeper_jaas.conf
                  -Dzookeeper.authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
                  -DrequireClientAuthScheme=sasl
                  -Dzookeeper.allowSaslFailedClients=false
    volumes:
      - /zoo/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - /zoo/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
      - ./secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.6
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: kafka
    user: root
    depends_on:
        - zookeeper
    ports:
        - "9092:9092"
        - "9094:9094"
    environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: SSL://:9092,SSL_LOCAL://localhost:9093,PLAINTEXT_DOCKER://kafka:9094
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://ip:9092,SSL_LOCAL://localhost:9093,PLAINTEXT_DOCKER://kafka:9094
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: SSL:SASL_SSL,SSL_LOCAL:SASL_SSL,PLAINTEXT_DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
        KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: false
        KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: true
        KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
        KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
        KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: broker.keystore.jks
        KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: pass
        KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: pass
        KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: broker.truststore.jks
        KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: pass
        KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: requested
        KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: " "
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: SSL
        KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
        KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: false
        KAFKA_SUPER_USERS: "User:admin"
        KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/broker_jaas.conf
    volumes:
        - ./secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
        - /kafka/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
`

Broker starts up and work fine, but I can't add ACL because
of error -
Caused by: 

    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed.

Caused by:

     javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching localhost found."

As you can see in docker compose - I already add "ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=" option and this didn't help. I can connect to broker via offset explorer from another host, so as far as I understand the DNS name is not checked in this case. But for some reason this check works when I'm trying to create ACL via executing 'docker exec kafka kafka-acls --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --command-config /etc/kafka/secrets/client.properties --add --allow-principal User:user --operation READ --topic topic --group user_group' command.
I'm using a root certificate in Kafka, so it doesn't have a DNS name.
What am I doing wrong?
And some clarification - I want to create a broker where a client can see and can connect only to topics where that client has an ACL. But I need the ability to administer that broker via localhost.
Maybe there are another posibiblities to achive it?
